# Missed shared library for Xamarin.Android.Things

Tags: xamarin.android

I face the following issue when when I try to use the `Xamarin.Android.Things` library, as I get the following error:

```
      Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(579, 2): [ADB0010]  Deployment failed
    Mono.AndroidTools.InstallFailedException: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY: Package couldn't be installed in /data/app/com.companyname.{App}-JGJrV86_aZgUGwbbuAao1w==: Package com.companyname.{App} requires unavailable shared library com.google.android.things; failing!]
       at Mono.AndroidTools.Internal.AdbOutputParsing.CheckInstallSuccess(String output, String packageName) in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/451/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Mono.AndroidTools/Internal/AdbOutputParsing.cs:line 346
       at Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice.<>c__DisplayClass97_0.<InstallPackage>b__0(Task`1 t) in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/451/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Mono.AndroidTools/AndroidDevice.cs:line 784
       at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromResultTask`1.InnerInvoke()
       at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at AndroidDeviceExtensions.<PushAndInstallPackage>d__11.MoveNext() in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/451/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Xamarin.AndroidTools/Devices/AndroidDeviceExtensions.cs:line 187
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
       at AndroidDeviceExtensions.<PushAndInstallPackage>d__11.MoveNext() in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/451/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Xamarin.AndroidTools/Devices/AndroidDeviceExtensions.cs:line 203
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
       at Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploySession.<InstallPackage>d__116.MoveNext() in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/451/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Xamarin.AndroidTools/Sessions/AndroidDeploySession.cs:line 469
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
       at Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploySession.<RunAsync>d__110.MoveNext() in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/451/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Xamarin.AndroidTools/Sessions/AndroidDeploySession.cs:line 221
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploySession.<RunLoggedAsync>d__108.MoveNext() in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/451/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Xamarin.AndroidTools/Sessions/AndroidDeploySession.cs:line 123
```

The reason I use this library is that my tested application during paring returns **extraPairingVariant** = `PairingVariantConsent` that is part of `PairingParams.PairingVariantConsent` of `Android.Things` library ...

Here is example how I use it in my `Xamarin.Android` mobile app:

```cs
case BluetoothDevice.ActionPairingRequest:
{
    object obj = intent.GetParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.ExtraDevice);
    BluetoothDevice device = (obj as BluetoothDevice)!;
    var extraPairingVariant = intent.GetIntExtra(BluetoothDevice.ExtraPairingVariant, -1);
    switch (extraPairingVariant)
    {
        case PairingParams.PairingVariantPin:
        {
            if (TrySetPin(device, "0000"))
            {
                InvokeAbortBroadcast();
            }
        }
            break;
        case PairingParams.PairingVariantPasskeyConfirmation:
        case PairingParams.PairingVariantConsent:
        {
            device.SetPairingConfirmation(true);
        }
            break;
    }
}
```

I guess maybe `Xamarin.Android.Things` is not intended to work on Mobile Phone ?
But what should I use then instead of `PairingParams.PairingVariantConsent` ?

Comment: You use Xamarin.Android.Thing on real device or Emulator? And you have already setupped Raspberry Pi with Android Things?

Comment: I got this error trying to debug my app on Mobile Phone

Comment: Can you share how to use Xamarin.Android.Thing in your project?

Comment: I've updated question with code example of usage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like issue happens because I tried to use his library on Android Mobile Phone where it is not supported ...
As I got, the main intent of this library is to be used on hardware, device where it is installed, like Raspberry Pi, Beagle Bone and etc.